# How to set a pdf background color?

Tags: python, reportlab

I want to generate a p d f with report lab. I need to change the background color of the exported p d f ( not FONT color, BACKGROUND color ). Thanks!

Comment: Show the code you have so far

Comment: Did you try checking the user guide and searching for "background" in it? https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4


c=canvas.Canvas("Background",pagesize=A4)
c.setFillColorRGB(1,0,0)
c.rect(5,5,652,792,fill=1)
c.setTitle("Background")
c.showPage()
c.save()
```