# Change the page color of a pdf using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Is it possible to change the background color of a pdf using PyPDF2 or any other libraries?

Comment: Have you tried searching the documentation?

Comment: Yup. Couldn't find anything relevant. Looked StackOverFlow questions, but seems like no one asked this question or am I asking the wrong question? Still looking :)

Comment: Im not seeing anything here on the Page Object (https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html#PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject). Perhaps just add an image as the background?

Comment: Or if PyPDF2 has shapes add colored shapes to the background?

Comment: Relevant [How to set a pdf background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57412177/7414759)